# Как сделать заголовок с уголками

Tags: html, css

Всем привет
Не могли бы подсказать как без костылей правильно сверстать такой элемент?
С помощью чистого html/css
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну например это просто два квадрата, у каждого из которых видимы 2 стороны

Comment: А что значит "правильно"? Мне кажется варианто такая масса, что неправильное это разве что делать это через CSS1)) я хз.. пользователь всё равно вас не упрекнёт за это))

Comment: вешаете на этот заголовок пару псевдо-элементов(before, after) с соответствующими border'ами. и цепляете их абсолютным позиционированием к границам заголовка(сам заголовок придется сделать relative). еще можно поиграться с `border-image` например

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложу такой, достаточно простой вариант. Толщина уголка регулируется при помощи значений свойства border, длина и высота - при помощи значений свойств width, height

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

h1 {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.btl {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 3px solid gold;
  border-top: 3px solid gold;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.bbr {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-right: 3px solid gold;
  border-bottom: 3px solid gold;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="btl"></div>
  <h1>ОБРАЗОВАНИЕ</h1>
  <div class="bbr"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-inline: auto;
  padding: .5em .75em;
  position: relative;
}

h1::before, h1::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 1em;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border: .25em solid orange;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

h1::before {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: none; 
}

h1::after {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none; 
}
```

```html
<h1>Образование</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
            .mane_text{
                text-align: center;
                font-family: Arial;
                margin: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
                letter-spacing: 3px;
                color: black;
                font-size: 35px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                user-select: text;
            }
            #block_1{
                width: 2%;
                height: 30px;
                border-left: 7px solid #FBD66A;
                border-top: 7px solid #FBD66A;
                color: white;
                border-top-right-radius: 5px;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
                position: relative;
                left: 580px;
                bottom: 53px;
            }
            #block_2{
                width: 2%;
                height: 30px;
                border-left: 7px solid #FBD66A;
                border-top: 7px solid #FBD66A;
                color: white;
                border-top-right-radius: 5px;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
                position: relative;
                left: 890px;
                bottom: 53px;
                transform: scaleY(-1);
                transform: scaleX(-1);
                transform: rotate(180deg);
            }
            #block_parent{
              position: relative;
              left: -440px;
              user-select: none;
            }
```

```html
    <h1 class="mane_text">Образования</h1>
    <div id="block_parent">
      <div id="block_1">.</div>
      <div id="block_2">.</div>
    </div>
```

Вот ещё один вариант реализации углов для текста, но также добавил border-radius

Answer (score 0):

```css
h1 {
  --bw: .25em;
  --bl: 1em;

  /* Отрежу лишний пиксель чтобч не было артефактов сглаживания */
  --bwex: calc(var(--bw) + 1px);

  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-inline: auto;
  border: var(--bw) solid orange;
  padding: .25em .5em;
  clip-path: polygon(
    0 0,
    var(--bl) 0,
    var(--bl) var(--bwex),
    calc(100% - var(--bwex)) var(--bwex),
    calc(100% - var(--bwex)) calc(100% - var(--bl)),
    100% calc(100% - var(--bl)),
    100% 100%,
    calc(100% - var(--bl)) 100%,
    calc(100% - var(--bl)) calc(100% - var(--bwex)),
    var(--bwex) calc(100% - var(--bwex)),
    var(--bwex) var(--bl),
    0 var(--bl)
  );
}
```

```html
<h1>Образование</h1>
```